# How to update two tables using subquery in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables

main table is

```
Complaintid Status  Templateid
123           2 
135           5      2
142           5      8
143           3 
145           5
```

Second table

```
Parent_complaint_id Currentstatus   Reopen  Photo
123                     0             0     Abc.jpg
123                     2             0     Abc.jpg
135                     5             0     Xyz.jpg
142                     5             0     Sim.jpg
143                     3             0     123.jpg
145                     2             0     Ing.jpg
145                     5             0     Ing.jpg
```

After updation first table

```
Complaintid Status  Templateid
123          2  
135          1       2
142          1       8
143          3  
145          5
```

After updation second table

```
Parent_complaint_id Currentstatus   Reopen  Photo
123                  0                0     Abc.jpg
123                  2                0     Abc.jpg
135                  1                0     Xyz.jpg
142                  1                0     Sim.jpg
143                  3                0     123.jpg
145                  2                0     Ing.jpg
145                  5                0     Ing.jpg
```

Here is the first query

```
Update complaints 
set status='1' 
where templateid is not null
```

but i don't know how to add subquery in above query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
UPDATE second_table
SET Currentstatus = 1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM first_table
               WHERE first_table.Complaintid = second_table.Parent_complaint_id
                 AND first_table.templateid is not null )
```

Or

```
UPDATE second_table
SET Currentstatus = 1
FROM first_table
WHERE first_table.Complaintid = second_table.Parent_complaint_id
  AND first_table.templateid is not null
```

Or ... too many variants.

Comment: I have to update both tables

Comment: @sumitkundan Your "Here is the first query" successfully updates first table. Then use one of my queries to update second table. Wrap both queries into a transaction if needed. Anycase one query can update one table only, so you cannot to update both tables with one query.

Comment: @sumitkundan Of course you can try to move the first update to CTE with adding proper  RETURNING clause.